# Clarification on the definition of strongly NP-hard

Tags: complexity-theory

I am seeing two definitions of strongly NP-hard that seem to be slightly different:

1. A problem is strongly NP-hard if a strongly NP-complete problem has a polynomial time reduction to it.
2. A problem is strongly NP-hard if it is still NP-hard when all numbers in the input are bounded by a polynomial in the length of the input. Or equivalently, if it is still NP-hard when the input is given in unary.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_NP-completeness) gives Definition 1, but Definition 2 seems to be more common overall. Both definitions preclude the existence of a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm to such a problem. However, it seems to me that Definition 1 is stronger since there might exist a problem for which there is no pseudo-polynomial time algorithm, but also no strongly NP-complete problem can be reduced to it. This would be a strange problem indeed, but I don't see why it can't exist.

So am I missing something or is one of the definitions slightly off?

Comment: Wikipedia gives Definition 2: "A problem is said to be strongly NP-complete (NP-complete in the strong sense), if it remains so even when all of its numerical parameters are bounded by a polynomial in the length of the input." Definition 1 is meaningless unless you define what a strongly NP-complete problem is.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes, I understand that that is the definition of a strongly NP-complete problem. But my question is about the definition of a strongly NP-hard problem. And even if you take into account Wikipedia's definition of a strongly NP-complete problem, my point is that Wikipedia's definition of a strongly NP-hard problem ("A problem is said to be strongly NP-hard if a strongly NP-complete problem has a polynomial reduction to it."), aka Definition 1 above, doesn't seem to be equivalent to Definition 2.

Comment: Wikipedia isn't an authoritative resource, and often contains mistakes. I suggest ignoring it.

Comment: Ah okay! I have probably been trusting it a little bit too much.